# GWT SuggestBox: Rich suggestions instead of just text?

Tags: java, gwt, autocomplete

GWT's `SuggestBox` shows a list of inputs that match what the user has already typed. Can the suggestion list items contain arbitrary HTML or widgets instead of just strings? For example, I'd like to show an icon with some suggested items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer - yes, the suggestions can contain arbitrary HTML - just put this in the suggestion implementation for your SuggestOracle. For example:

```
public class CountrySuggestion implements Suggestion {
  ..snip..
  @Override
  public String getDisplayString() {
    return "<i>" + country.getName() + "</i><img src='icon.png'>";
  }
}
```

Comment: For this to work, make sure that the `SuggestOracle` overrides `isDisplayStringHTML` to return `true`.